# Nested relationship access with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

This is the problem. I have a booking table. It's properties are as follows

```
   -id
   -path_id
   -start_time
```

The path table is as follows

```
-id
-car_id
-fare
-start_location
-end_location
```

the car table

```
-id
-plate_number
-year_of_manufacture
-model
```

I have a Laravel application where the booking details need to be displayed.
The models have the relations described as

BookingDetails model:

```
public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
    }

    public function path()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Path::class);
    }
```

The controller gets the details with,

```
BookingDetails:with('route')->get();
```

I know I can use an if statement with the above and get the car plate number.
But is there a way I can get it with relations in Laravel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have failed to improvise here.
Did you try this?

Assuming what you need is the car plate number,

You could,

```
$details = BookingDetails:with('route')->get();
```

in the blade,

```
$details->route->car->plate_number
```

Check this and reply. And don't forget to mark as answer if found useful.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. But where in the blade?

Comment: Sorry. Confusion. I got it. This should be inside {{}}. Thanks.